# In VB6, do I need to call SysFreeString on strings allocated with SysAllocString?

Tags: c++, dll, com, memory-leaks, vb6

I have a VB6 app which uses a C++ COM DLL and BSTRs are passed between the two. I return BSTRs from the C++ DLL with `return ::SysAllocString(L"example");`.

Do I need to call `SysFreeString` on such a string in the following example?

```vb
Sub Main()
    Dim own_str As String
    Dim dll_str As String

    own_str = "my own string"
    dll_str = DllComObj.FunctionReturningString()
    ' when leaving the scope:
    ' no need to free own_str,
    ' do I need to free dll_str?
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you don't. VB6 will free them as BSTR is its native string format.

Comment: +1 See also Microsoft's [note on developing DLLs for use with VB6](http://vb.mvps.org/tips/vb5dll.asp)